# Crawling through list of hosts when some don't exist

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm using Paramiko to try and crawl through a list of hosts.  The code will work until one of the hosts in the list is unavailable. It produces this error.

```
  File "remote.py", line 12, in <module>
  ssh.connect(i, username='user', password='pass')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 296, in connect  
  sock.connect(addr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
  return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args) 
  socket.error: [Errno 113] No route to host
```

My Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import paramiko

host = ['cpu1','cpu2','cpu3']

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

for i in host:
    str(i)
    ssh.connect(i, username='user', password='pass')
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('w')
    print stdout.readlines()
    ssh.close()
```

I'm wanting the script to run through and execute the command. If it cannot connect to the host then skip and go to the next. Am I missing an if statement with some Paramiko parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try catching the exception, handling and maybe continuing if you so desire.

```
import paramiko

host = ['cpu1','cpu2','cpu3']

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

for i in host:
    str(i)
    try:
        ssh.connect(i, username='user', password='pass')
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('w')
        print stdout.readlines()
        ssh.close()
    except Exception as ex:
        print "Excetion: %s" % str(ex)
```

Always properly handle exceptions don't blindly escape them using `pass`, it can lead to hard to find bugs.

Comment: How is printing something to stdout whenever _any_ exception occurs less "blind" than passing on a single named exception?

Comment: because it will be logged one way or another, you could overwrite sys.stdout so its a file or you can pipe the output to a file, then you can parse that file, eithe rway just blindly `pass` feels extremely dangerous since theres no way for a programmer to ever detected it.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing any error handling; as the [documentation explains](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/) the `connect` method raises 4 different exceptions. In your case you hit `socket.error`.

As you want to ignore any connection errors and skip to the next host you can use the [`pass` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-pass_stmt) to ignore these errors and continue. It's important to not `pass` every exception only those that you want to.

```
import paramiko

hosts = ['cpu1','cpu2','cpu3']

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

for i in hosts:

    try:    
        ssh.connect(i, username='user', password='pass')
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('w')
        print stdout.readlines()
        ssh.close()
    except socket.error as e:
        pass
```